# What make messages to Facebook page not delivered?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-messenger, instant-messaging

I know that if you send a message to a person who isn't connected with you in Facebook, then the message will only has the status `Sent` until the person accepts it. However, my message to a page is also in the status `Sent`. I wonder if the admin of the page has to accept it so that the status can change to `Delivered`. Is that correct? Would the message be notified if the person doesn't install [Facebook Page Manage](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.pages.app) app?

Comment: Meta discussion: https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4608/63572

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having test it myself, I conclude:

- Yes, the message will only be marked as `Sent` even if it is successfully delivered to the page (which is almost instantly)
- When the admin of the page is on their personal account, only your last message will be displayed in the notification to them
- If they click on it it will be marked as `Seen` immediately. There is no need to go through the accept step
- It seems that the message doesn't show up in their Messenger app (I'm not sure about this)

Answer (score 3):

From [Facebook Help Center](https://www.facebook.com/help/411619238930367):

> When your message is delivered, it will be marked as sent. If your message fails to send, you'll see a message saying that it didn't go through and you'll have the option to send the message again.

It means your message already has been delivered.

If it's a public page and message icon is there then admin don't have to accept it. You message directly go the Page's inbox. Now, it's depend on Admin(s) if they want to respond to your message or not.

Yes, they will get notified in Page notification about the message even if they don't have install the app.

Note, using messages on Facebook and on [Messenger app](https://www.facebook.com/help/messenger-app/iphone/926389207386625/) is different.

Comment: so the admin will only receive notification if they visit the page? What if they just use their regular account?

Comment: I administer some pages. I do get alerts from messages to my pages, but Facebook's way of notifying is not always useful or consistent.

Comment: **"When your message is delivered, it will be marked as sent."** I think this is the source of confusion, since normally when a message is delivered it should be marked as delivered.

Comment: @Ooker: Hmm.. you can give your [feedback](https://www.facebook.com/help/feedback/) to Facebook.

Comment: think about it, this is only about messages in general, not about messages for pages in specific. I think there shouldn't be a difference, but it seems to be a difference for me. My messages are always marked as "sent", not "delivered"

Comment: @Ooker: We are not associated to Facebook. This is independent site to help people related to their queries about web application end user. We cannot do anything about any feature of a any web application. You can provide your feedback directly to Facebook if you want.

Comment: No, I know that already. I just say that it is possible that this answer doesn't work for message to fanpage in specific. Check my answer below.